# Mining - One card gets a lot of incorrect shares even with stock BIOS

Tags: mining, miner, claymore

Just picked up a Sapphire Nitro+ 580 4GB, and after BIOS modding it was kicking out incorrect shares constantly.  I went back to the stock BIOS and with a modest memory overclock it's still getting one every 5 minutes or so while also getting some accepted shares.

It's got Hynix memory and 78% ASIC quality.  The rig is three 480s, a 570, and this 580 mining on nanopool, and it's very stable.  None of the other cards get incorrect shares that I've ever seen.

Is this card simply a lemon?

Comment: Having the same issue -- did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party here, but some cards do simply have worse silicon. What i find helps is setting straps no lower that 1750, and the memory clock around 2020MHz. Also watch the card to see if you get incorrect shares right away, or after a few minutes of mining. If it takes a while to start seeing incorrect shares, you most likely have a hot area in your setup. If it happens right away, your card is having an overclocking difficulty.